# Scraping with Python - XPath issue

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm currently in the process of researching scraping and I've been following a tutorial on Youtube. The tutorial is using 'Scrapy' and I've managed to scrape data from the website previewed in the tutorial. However, now I've tried scraping another website with no success.

From my understanding, the problem is from the Xpath that I'm using. I've tried several Xpath testing/generator websites with no success.

This is the following XML code:

```
<div class="price" currentmouseover="94">
<del currentmouseover="96">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" currentmouseover="90"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>3.60</span>
</del>
<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" currentmouseover="123"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol" currentmouseover="92">€</span>3.09</span></ins></div>
```

I'm currently using the following code:

```
 def parse(self,response):
    for title in response.xpath("//div[@class='Price']"):
        yield {
            'title_text': title.xpath(".//span[@class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount']/text()").extract_first()
        }
```

I've also tried using //span[@class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount'].

I want my output to be '3.09', instead, I'm getting null when I export it to a JSON file. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**
I've managed to fix the problem with Jack Fleeting's answer. Since I've had problems understanding Xpath I've been trying different websites in order to get a further understanding of how Xpath works. Unfortunately, I'm stuck in another example.

```
<div class="add-product"><strong><small>€3.11</small> €3.09</strong></div>
```

I'm using the following snippet:

```
 l.add_xpath('price', ".//div[@class='add-product']/strong[1]")
```

My expectation is to output the 3.09, however, I'm outputting both numbers. I've tried using a minimum function, but Xpath 1.0 does not support it. ie: since I wanted to output the actual (discounted) value of the item

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath expression, and see if it works:

```
//div[@class='price']/ins/span
```

Note that `price` is lower case, as in you html.

Comment: I've changed the first xpath to `"//div[@class='product-wrap']"` and I've updated the second part with your suggestion. It worked perfectly.  In the meantime, I've added the product name as well. I'm currently trying to yield the product name and price in the same row. I will update my post if I don't manage by tomorrow. Thanks a lot Jack.